# C# scheduler tools

Tags: c#, asp.net, scheduler

I’m loath to ask another scheduler question here, I’ve read through dozens, but it’s still not clear to me what tools would best fit my need. I have three requirements for a reporting app:

1. User invoked
2. fixed scheduled
3. user scheduled.

I have an ASP.NET forms app to cover #1 and a C# console app to handle #2 but now #3 has been added to the mix.
So for the user scheduled reports I need to:

- Present the user with a schedule selector and save their selection (into SQL Server?)
- Have an app that checks the database for jobs to run/schedule
- App to run the query and format the report

I suppose the latter two could be a single app but I’ve read it’s hard to debug service apps so keeping them separate may be good.  I don’t know what parts of my requirements are met by Quartz.net and I’ve seen separate GUI tools (DayPilot) and backend (Task Manager API, CodePlex taskscheduler) mentioned.  Not having used any of these I’m hoping to minimize my false starts.

Comment: Why the down vote? Where's the love?

Comment: @Eric thanks Eric, I attempted to ask a succinct question, guess it isn't up to the standards of some. At least I can't go below zero (I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SQL Server, then you should use [SQL Server Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx), which does all three.

Comment: not sure this is what we'll use but it's a good solution, thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem. Its included with SQL Server Express and up, so its no additional cost.

Answer (score 1):

If you require job scheduler try using [hangfire.io](http://hangfire.io)